# Kaniko in Tekton pipeline on Openshift returns error checking push permissions

Tags: openshift, tekton, kaniko, openshift-pipelines

We have a Tekton pipeline task in Openshift which uses Kaniko to build a container image and then push it to a external registry.

The build step of the task always fails with the error:

```
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "xxxxxxx.io/xxxxxxxxxxx/frontend:frontend-secure-pipeline-csd6ur": POST https://xxxxxxx.io/v2/xxxxxxxxxxx/frontend/blobs/uploads/: DENIED: You are not authorized to access the specified resource. See https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Registry?topic=Registry-troubleshoot-access-denied; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:xxxxxxxxxxx/frontend Type:repository] map[Action:push Class: Name:xxxxxxxxxxx/frontend Type:repository]]
```

The task yaml is (annotations, comments and later steps removed for brevity)...

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: source-to-image-cache
  namespace: openshift-pipelines
  resourceVersion: '259117173'
  uid: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
spec:
  params:
    - description: The path to the dockerfile to build
      name: pathToDockerfile
      type: string
    - default: .
      description: >-
        The build context used by Kaniko
        (https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#kaniko-build-contexts)
      name: pathToContext
      type: string
    - default: ''
      description: Image tag
      name: imageTag
      type: string
    - default: sbu-pipeline
      description: Is the name of the base image registry namespace secret
      name: base-reg-secret-name
      type: string
    - default: sbu-pipeline
      description: Is the name of the built image registry namespace secret
      name: build-reg-secret-name
      type: string
    - default: ''
      description: >-
        This is the URL to save the built image to - used with
        imageRespositoryPath below
      name: imageRegistryUrl
      type: string
    - default: ''
      description: >-
        This is the repository path at the imageRegistryUrl to save the built
        image to
      name: imageRepositoryPath
      type: string
  results:
    - description: The image SHA code for the built application
      name: image-digest
      type: string
  steps:
    - image: 'uk.icr.io/sbu-pipeline/alpine-curl-jq:6'
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      name: merge-json
      resources: {}
      script: >
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        set +x
        
        printf "\nSorting out config.json for Kaniko.\n"

        diff /home/.dockerwip/base.dockerconfigjson
        /home/.dockerwip/build.dockerconfigjson -q

        myDiff=$?

        if [ "$myDiff" -gt 0 ]; then
          # Hopefully short-term fix until Kaniko supports multiple auths...
          cp /home/.dockerwip/base.dockerconfigjson /home/.docker/config.json
        else
          cp /home/.dockerwip/base.dockerconfigjson /home/.docker/config.json
        fi

        printf "\nFinished sorting out config.json for Kaniko.\n"

      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/.dockerwip/base.dockerconfigjson
          name: base-registry-creds
          subPath: base.dockerconfigjson
        - mountPath: /home/.dockerwip/build.dockerconfigjson
          name: build-registry-creds
          subPath: build.dockerconfigjson
        - mountPath: /home/.docker
          name: docker-config
    - resources: {}
      name: build
      command:
        - /kaniko/executor
      env:
        - name: DOCKER_CONFIG
          value: /kaniko/.docker/
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /kaniko/.docker/
          name: docker-config
      image: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.16.0'
      args:
        - >-
          --dockerfile=$(workspaces.source.path)/$(inputs.params.pathToDockerfile)
        - >-
          --destination=$(params.imageRegistryUrl)/$(params.imageRepositoryPath):$(inputs.params.imageTag)
        - '--context=$(workspaces.source.path)/$(inputs.params.pathToContext)'
        - '--single-snapshot=true'
        - '--image-name-with-digest-file=$(workspaces.source.path)/image-digest'
        - '--cache=true'
        - '--cache-copy-layers=true'
        - '--use-new-run=true'
  volumes:
    - emptyDir: {}
      name: docker-config
    - name: base-registry-creds
      secret:
        items:
          - key: .dockerconfigjson
            path: base.dockerconfigjson
        secretName: $(params.base-reg-secret-name)
    - name: build-registry-creds
      secret:
        items:
          - key: .dockerconfigjson
            path: build.dockerconfigjson
        secretName: $(params.build-reg-secret-name)
  workspaces:
    - name: source
```

I've tested the credentials locally and everything seems fine. I can mount the secret containing the docker credentials in another container and then successfully login, pull and push images. The error only occurs with Kaniko. It seems Kaniko is not reading the DOCKER_CONFIG environment variable. I've tried multiple different Kaniko versions without success.

Any suggestions on possible fixes or next steps in debugging?